# Libevent use too much CPU

Tags: memcached, cpu-usage, libevent

Recently I write a simple example using libevent,

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stddef.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <event.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <netinet/tcp.h>

    #define bool char
    #define false 0
    #define true 1

enum conn_states
{
    conn_listening, /**< the socket which listens for connections */
    conn_new_cmd, /**< Prepare connection for next command */
    conn_waiting, /**< waiting for a readable socket */
    conn_read, /**< reading in a command line */
    conn_parse_cmd, /**< try to parse a command from the input buffer */
    conn_write, /**< writing out a simple response */
    conn_swallow, /**< swallowing unnecessary bytes w/o storing */
    conn_closing, /**< closing this connection */
};

/**
 * The structure representing a connection into memcached.
 * Used when processing request for worker threads
 */
typedef struct conn conn;
struct conn
{
    char *rbuf; /** buffer to read commands into */
    char *rcurr; /** but if we parsed some already, this is where we stopped */
    int rsize; /** total allocated size of rbuf */
    int rbytes; /** how much data have we read*/

    char *wbuf; /* buffer to write*/
    char *wcurr;
    int wsize; /* sizeof(buf)*/
    int wbytes;/* strlen(buf)*/

    int sfd;
    enum conn_states state;
    struct event event;
    short ev_flags;
    short which; /** which events were just triggered */

    /** which state to go into after finishing current write */
    enum conn_states write_and_go;
    void *write_and_free; /** free this memory after finishing writing */

    /* data for the swallow state */
    int sbytes; /* how many bytes to swallow */

    /*No care about UDP*/

    bool noreply; /* True if the reply should not be sent. */
    /* current stats command */
    struct
    {
        char *buffer;
        size_t size;
        size_t offset;
    } stats;

    conn *next; /* Used for generating a list of conn structures */
};

/** file scope variables **/
struct event_base *main_base;


//the master listen fd stores here
//also the first node of listen conn queue
conn *listen_conn = NULL;

//how to pass which to event_handler?
void event_handler(const int fd, const short which, void *arg)
{
    conn *c;

    fprintf(stderr, "event_handler going to work for %d\n", fd);

    /* wait for next event */
    return;
}


/*
 * Frees a connection.
 */
void conn_free(conn *c)
{
    if (c)
    {
        if (c->rbuf)
            free(c->rbuf);
        if (c->wbuf)
            free(c->wbuf);
        free(c);
    }
}


/**
 *  create a new conn, and set the conn's event
 */
conn *conn_new(const int sfd, enum conn_states init_state,
        const int event_flags, const int read_buffer_size,  struct event_base *base)
{
    conn *c = NULL;

    if (NULL == c) //c=NULL  at first time
    {
        if (!(c = (conn *) calloc(1, sizeof(conn))))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "calloc failed");
            return NULL;
        }

        c->rbuf = c->wbuf = 0;
        c->rsize = read_buffer_size;
        c->wsize = 2048;
        c->rbuf = (char *) malloc((size_t) c->rsize);
        c->wbuf = (char *) malloc((size_t) c->wsize);

        if (c->rbuf == 0 || c->wbuf == 0)
        {
            conn_free(c);
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed");
            return NULL;
        }

    }

    c->sfd = sfd;
    c->state = init_state;
    c->rbytes = c->wbytes = 0;
    c->wcurr = c->wbuf;
    c->rcurr = c->rbuf;

    c->write_and_go = init_state;
    c->write_and_free = 0;

    c->noreply = false;

    event_set(&c->event, sfd, event_flags, event_handler, (void *) c);
    event_base_set(base, &c->event);
    c->ev_flags = event_flags;

    if (event_add(&c->event, 0) == -1)
    {
        conn_free(c);
        fprintf(stderr, "event_add failed");
        return NULL;
    }

    return c;
}

static int new_socket(struct addrinfo *ai)
{
    int sfd;
    int flags;

    if ((sfd = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol)) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if ((flags = fcntl(sfd, F_GETFL, 0)) < 0
            || fcntl(sfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "setting O_NONBLOCK");
        close(sfd);
        return -1;
    }
    return sfd;
}


int server_socket(int port)
{
    int sfd;
    struct linger ling =
    { 0, 0 };
    struct addrinfo *ai;
    struct addrinfo *next;
    struct addrinfo hints =
    { .ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE, .ai_family = AF_UNSPEC };
    char port_buf[NI_MAXSERV];
    int error;
    int success = 0;
    int flags = 1;

    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if (port == -1)
    {
        port = 0;
    }
    snprintf(port_buf, sizeof(port_buf), "%d", port);
    error = getaddrinfo(NULL, port_buf, &hints, &ai);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo(): %s", gai_strerror(error));
        return -1;
    }

    for (next = ai; next; next = next->ai_next)
    {
        conn *listen_conn_add;
        if ((sfd = new_socket(next)) == -1)
        {
            /* getaddrinfo can return "junk" addresses,
             * we make sure at least one works before erroring.
             */
            if (errno == EMFILE)
            {
                /* ...unless we're out of fds */
                fprintf(stderr, "server_socket failed");
                exit(-1);
            }
            continue;
        }

        /*will not care about ipv6 here*/

        setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *) &flags, sizeof(flags));
        error = setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (void *) &flags,
                sizeof(flags));
        if (error != 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt");

        error = setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (void *) &ling,
                sizeof(ling));
        if (error != 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt");

        /** TCP_NODELAY is for a specific purpose; to disable the Nagle buffering
            algorithm. It should only be set for applications that send frequent
            small bursts of information without getting an immediate response,
            where timely delivery of data is required  (the canonical example is
            mouse movements)*/

        error = setsockopt(sfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *) &flags,
                sizeof(flags));
        if (error != 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt");

        if (bind(sfd, next->ai_addr, next->ai_addrlen) == -1)
        {
            if (errno != EADDRINUSE)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "bind failed");
                close(sfd);
                freeaddrinfo(ai);
                return -1;
            }
            close(sfd);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            success++;
            if (next->ai_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
            {
                union
                {
                    struct sockaddr_in in;
                    struct sockaddr_in6 in6;
                } my_sockaddr;
                socklen_t len = sizeof(my_sockaddr);
                if (getsockname(sfd, (struct sockaddr*) &my_sockaddr, &len) == 0)
                {
                    if (next->ai_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Server listenning at port : %u",
                                ntohs(my_sockaddr.in.sin_port));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!(listen_conn_add = conn_new(sfd, conn_listening,
                EV_READ | EV_PERSIST, 1, main_base)))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to create listening connection");
            exit(-1);
        }
        listen_conn_add->next = listen_conn;
        listen_conn = listen_conn_add; //the way to add a node
        fprintf(stderr, "<%d listen tcp conn added to queue", sfd);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(ai);

    return success;
}

int main()
{

    /* initialize main thread libevent instance */
    main_base = event_init();

    errno = 0;
    if (server_socket(22222) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to listen on TCP port %d", 22222);
        return -1;
    }

    if (event_base_loop(main_base, 0) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to event_base_loop");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but when it is running, the cpu is almost 99%.

This code piece is from memcached, memcached worked very well then!

Please help!

but when it is running, the cpu is almost 99%.

This code piece is from memcached, memcached worked very well then!

Please help!

but when it is running, the cpu is almost 99%.

This code piece is from memcached, memcached worked very well then!

Please help!

but when it is running, the cpu is almost 99%.

This code piece is from memcached, memcached worked very well then!

Please help!

but when it is running, the cpu is almost 99%.

This code piece is from memcached, memcached worked very well then!

Please help!

but when it is running, the cpu is almost 99%.

This code piece is from memcached, memcached worked very well then!

Please help!

but when it is running, the cpu is almost 99%.

This code piece is from memcached, memcached worked very well then!

Please help!

but when it is running, the cpu is almost 99%.

This code piece is from memcached, memcached worked very well then!

Please help!

but when it is running, the cpu is almost 99%.

This code piece is from memcached, memcached worked very well then!

Please help!

but when it is running, the cpu is almost 99%.

This code piece is from memcached, memcached worked very well then!

Please help!

but when it is running, the cpu is almost 99%.

This code piece is from memcached, memcached worked very well then!

Please help!

thx

Comment: Problem solved!

forgot

listen(fd, backlog);

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see upon inspection is the fprintf in the "event_handler" which means that every time you receive some data, this will cost you. fprintf and sprintf are notoriously slow and may be impacted by the way that libevent works with the kernel. Regardless.. they take a lot of cpu and if you are receiving events frequently....

Another thing that I don't see in your code is where you accept new connections. Libevent has two ways to do this..

```
listener = evconnlistener_new_bind(base, accept_conn_cb, NULL,
        LEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE|LEV_OPT_REUSEABLE, -1,
        (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
```

and

```
event_set(&ev_accept, listen_fd, EV_READ|EV_PERSIST, on_accept, NULL);
```

It seems a little strange, or disorganized. How do you accept new connections?